# Compile error for hibernate-validator country specific constraints

Tags: maven, hibernate-validator

My project is a JEE with jax-rs/resteasy implementation and I'm using resteasy validation with beans validations(hibernate-validator). When I try to build project by maven the error is:

> employee.java:[6,10] package org.hibernate.validator.constraints.br does not exist
> cannot find symbol class CPF

```
package br.com.example.dto;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.br.CPF;

public class Employee {

    @NotBlank(message = "blank")
    @CPF(message = "invalid")
    private String cpf;
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I remove @CPF validation everything works fine.

My question: why `<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>` that was declared inside of `wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools` was not working for this country specific constraint?

Comment: That looks basically correct, though you didn't show the whole pom.xml.   Did you know the BOM import you showed above belongs in the `<dependencyManagement>` whereas the `hibernate-validator` artifact itself is just a regular dependency in `<dependencies>` ?

Comment: Yes, inside of this BOM there are a `<artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8</artifactId>` and from him come `hibernate-validator`. But why this @CPF constraint only work if I explicity declare `hibernate-validator` on my root pom.xml?

Answer (score 3):

Importing a [`BOM`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) does nothing (in terms of setting dependencies). You will still have to declare dependencies required for your project.

But `BOM` is pretty good for dependency versioning. In Maven you should set that BOM file as the parent of your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
        <version>26.1.3.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- required dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ... -->

</project>
```

Or as a dependency in the `<dependencyManagement>` section:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- required dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>26.1.3.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- ... -->

</project>
```

And after that you don't need to specify any version of the dependency declared in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the parent pom file. For example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

I also looked at the `wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools` and didn't find `hibernate-validator`. You should check this out.

Comment: Now I got how BOM works. Inside of BOM `wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools` there are a <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8</artifactId> and from him come `hibernate-validator` because this is a regular pom.xml, I confirmed by inspecting effective pom.

Comment: I don´t understand why you declared BOM inside a `<parent>` instead `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>...`

Comment: @KauanMocelin you can declare a BOM as dependency, I added this option  to my answer. You should consider this as a variant of declaring the BOM

Comment: @KauanMocelin I got you. I haven't seen the first comment. Can you show where `wildfly-jakartaee8`  is located?